# Добавление заголовка WS-Security в запрос авто созданного service reference С#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день. Прошу помощи. Работаю в Visual Studio 2015. Добавил ссылку на нужную мне WSDL, в папке Service reference была автоматически созданна структура для доступа к этому сервису. Суть в том что мне нужно подключиться к другому сервису, который использует валидацию через WS-Security. Если запустить проект сейчас, то выводит ошибку "No WS-Security header found".

Вот так подключен сервис в Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WsdlPortSoap111">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://iais-test.kemsu.ru:80/DekanatService-0_1_1/ws"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsdlPortSoap111"
    contract="kemsu.services.p.WsdlPort" name="WsdlPortSoap111">
   </endpoint>
</client>
```

Вот такой метод я использую чтобы отправить запрос:

```
WsdlPortClient client;    
List<Specialities> specialities = new List<Specialities>();  
GetSpecialitiesResponse resp = new GetSpecialitiesResponse(); 
GetSpecialitiesRequest req = new GetSpecialitiesRequest();   
req.institute_id = instid;            
resp = client.GetSpecialities(req);
Diplom.kemsu.services.p.speciality[] spec = resp.list;
```

Пробовал делать вот так, но нужный мне заголовок это не добавляет:

```
client = new WsdlPortClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
```

Полный код ошибки:

```
No WS-Security header found

Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса.     
Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода. 
Сведения об исключении: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: No WS-Security header found
```

Ошибка источника(эти строки из созданного автоматически файла Reference.cs в подключенном сервисе):

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
Diplom.kemsu.services.p.GetInstitutesResponse1
Diplom.kemsu.services.p.WsdlPort.GetInstitutes(Diplom.kemsu.services.p.GetInstitutesRequest1 request){
return base.Channel.GetInstitutes(request);
}
```

UPD. Нашел нужное решение. Если кто-то наткнулся на этот вопрос, то вот как я его решил:

Для начала добавил два класса:

Первый:

```
            namespace YourProj.Infrastructure
            {    public class InspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
                {
                    public string LastRequestXML
                    {
                        get
                        {
                            return myMessageInspector.LastRequestXML;
                        }
                    }

                    public string LastResponseXML
                    {
                        get
                        {
                            return myMessageInspector.LastResponseXML;
                        }
                    }


                    private MyMessageInspector myMessageInspector = new MyMessageInspector();
                    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
                    {

                    }

                    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
                    {

                    }

                    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
                    {

                    }


                    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
                    {
                        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(myMessageInspector);
                    }
                }
                public class MyMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
                {
                    public string LastRequestXML { get; private set; }
                    public string LastResponseXML { get; private set; }
                    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
                    {
                        LastResponseXML = reply.ToString();
                    }

                    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
                    {
                        //LastRequestXML = request.ToString();
                        MessageHeader messageHeadersElement = new SecurityHeader("user", "pass");
                        request.Headers.Add(messageHeadersElement);
                        LastRequestXML = request.ToString();
                        return request;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Второй:

```
namespace YourProj.Infrastructure
{
    public class SecurityHeader : System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader
    {
        public string userName;
        public string password;
        static object locker = new object();
        static Guid Generate15UniqueDigits()
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public SecurityHeader(string n,string p)
        {
            userName = n;
            password = p;
        }

        protected override void OnWriteStartHeader(System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", Name, Namespace);

            writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "wsu", null, Namespace);

        }

        protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion)
        {
            DateTime time = new DateTime();
            time = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var timeexp = time.AddMinutes(1);
            string Created = time.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
            string Expires = timeexp.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");

            //TimeStamp ts = new TimeStamp();


            UsernameToken userToken = new UsernameToken(userName, password, PasswordOption.SendHashed);

            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "UsernameToken", Namespace);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "wsu", null, userToken.Id);

            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Username", Namespace);
            writer.WriteValue(userToken.Username);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Password", Namespace);
            writer.WriteValue(userToken.Password);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Nonce", Namespace);
            writer.WriteValue(userToken.Nonce);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("wsu", "Created", null);
            writer.WriteValue(userToken.Created.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'"));
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            Guid g = Generate15UniqueDigits();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsu", "Timestamp", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("wsu", "Id", null, "TS-" + g);

            writer.WriteStartElement("wsu", "Created", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            writer.WriteValue(Created);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("wsu", "Expires", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            writer.WriteValue(Expires);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();

        }

        public override string Name
        {
            get { return "Security"; }
        }

        public override string Namespace
        {
            get { return "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Эти два класса нужны для того, чтобы перехватить сообщение и внести необходимые вам правки. А именно это делает метод BeforeSendRequest в классе InspectorBehavior (о чем собственно и говорит его название). Сами правки вносятся в методе OnWriteHeaderContents класса SecurityHeader. Далее следует его добавить к порту через который вы соединяетесь с нужным вам сервером. Я это делаю следующим образом:

```
            client = new WsdlPortClient(); // объявляем переменную порта
            var requestInterceptor = new InspectorBehavior();  //создаем перехватчик запроса
            client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(requestInterceptor); // добавляем перехватчик запроса, чтобы записать в header security заголовок
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user"; // вносим имя пользователя
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass"; // и пароль
```

После этого у меня все заработало. Все эти танцы с бубном, как я понял, нужны были т.к. сервер к которому я подключаюсь не поддерживает HTTPS соединения. Поэтому выкрутился вот так,может кому-то поможет.

Comment: попробуйте вместо `TransportCredentialOnly` вставить `TransportWithMessageCredential`

Comment: @Ruslan_K Если я изменяю TransportCredentialOnly на TransportWithMessageCredential то вылезает другая ошбка: "Представленная схема URI 'HTTPS' является недействительным; Ожидается, 'HTTP'. Имя параметра: via"